# React Native listView item delete not properly removing item

Tags: javascript, ios, listview, reactjs, native

Running some example code, I am running into an issue where the listView does not properly rerender a list that has been modified. For example, I have a hardcoded array of objects like:

```
datasetsItems = [
    {firstObjectWithMultipleParams},
    {secondObjectWithMultipleParams},
    ...
]
```

Then I created a button that did the following:

```
datasetsItems.splice(1,1) // To delete the object at index 1
this.setState({dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(
    datasetsItems
)});
```

However, this renders it with the last object in the array deleted, not the one specified at the index. I checked in the debugger and the splice function is working properly and deleting the requested object so it is not an issue with the splicing function.

I then tried the following:

```
datasetsItems = [...datasetsItems.slice(0,1),...datasetsItems.slice(2,datasetsItems.length)];
this.setState({dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(
    datasetsItems
)});
```

And this works and renders the list as expected without the object at index 1. So then I did the following, just to test:

```
datasetsItems.splice(1,1);
let newDs = datasetsItems.slice();
this.setState({dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(
    newDs
)});
```

But this doesn't work, and fails in the same way as the first example.

Is there a reason for this behaviour? I am also wondering if the way I am doing it with slicing gets rid of React's ability to just modify the changed row and therefore fully rerenders everything?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a clone of your original dataset to update the state. I had the same problem and managed to fix it by deep copying the array before doing this:

```
this.setState({
   dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newDs)
});
```

Here is a piece of my code:

```
//delete some items from old_array

var new_array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(old_array));

this.setState({
   dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(new_array)
});
```

It might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

When an empty data is involved like fetch did not find a data result, I used like this to flush the ListView :

```html
this.setState({ dataSource: 
                    this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows({}),
                loaded: true,
                    });
```